# Javascript Object literal assignment

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am using backbone.js for creating an application. I have code JS code as follows,

```
window.RequestsView = Backbone.View.extend({

initialize:function ( input ) {

    console.log('input ' + JSON.stringify(input) );

    this.variables = {   request_id:input.model.id,
                         status:input.model.status,
                         mavenGav:input.model.mavenGav, 
                         email:input.model.emailId, 
                         errorNo:input.model.errorNo, 
                         errorDesc:input.model.errorDesc };

    console.log("variables : "+ JSON.stringify( this.variables ) );

    this.template = _.template(tpl.get('requests'));
    var out = this.template( input );

    console.log("out: "+ JSON.stringify( out ) );

    // deep copy the object
    this.request =  $.extend( true, {},  input);
}
```

});

When I debug this in chrome debugger, I get the following logs,

```
input {"model":{"mavenGav":"fgdfgfdgdfg:fgdfgfd:gdfgdfg","repositories":["dfgdfgdfgf"],"emailId":"gdfg","id":1083,"createdTime":null,"status":"CREATED","errorNo":0,"errorDesc":null}}
requests.js:12variables : {"request_id":1083}
```

There are no errors. What happens to the rest of the javascript literal that got assigned to  this.variables ?

Comment: Log just the object: `console.log(this.variables);`. I'm guessing the other properties are `undefined`, which are being omitted from the JSON because [`undefined` is not an allowed value](http://json.org/).

Comment: When I test this in jsfiddle I get the correct answer: http://jsfiddle.net/8BwPn/1/ Hmzzz.

Comment: i have updated the code http://jsfiddle.net/8BwPn/4/   , now it doesn't print anything. this is the question I have. can I use variables inside object literals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`undefined` values are not stringified to json, because json only knows numbers, strings, booleans, null and objects/arrays. So the properties exist, but they "get lost" in conversion.

Try `console.debug("variables :",this.variables)`, that will let you inspect the variables object.

Comment: since this object is a backbone model, the way to get the values is using the 'get' method. The console.log prints it as if it is a regular JS object. But, when you like to access the member variable, use the 'get' method.